# Unix Bash script - How to Limit for loop through files to only process 10 at a time

Tags: bash, for-loop, unix

I am banging my head against a wall and I'm certain I'm just being dense.

I am attempting to run a for loop with a lftp command against files in a watched folder basically a backup and move process. But due to the way LFTP and the loop works if I process files on the destination before everything is done I get a failure.

So what I want to do is read all files with *.log and then if there are say 20 files only process 10, then on its next run process 10 files again eventually it will be at a point of 1 file at a time.
I can loop through everything fine. just can not seem to figure out how to only read the first 10 files as I say.

```
for FILE in *.log; do
lftp -p 2252 -u $FTPUser,$FTPPass $Location <<EOF
set ftp:ssl-allow no
set xfer:use-temp-file on
set xfer:temp-file-name *.tmp
set log:file/xfer /log/LFTP_$FILE.log;
mput $LogPath/$FILE
quit
EOF
   if [ $? == "0" ]; then
        rm $LogPath/$FILE
    else
        echo "Error"
    fi
done;
```

Comment: why does `for` use `*.log` but `mput` refers to `$LogPath/` ?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one `lftp` connection per batch.

Also, [don't use upper case for private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization), and [quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable); see also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern), and take care to send diagnostic messages to standard error, not standard output.

```
files=(*.log)
for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i+=10)); do
    slice=("${files[0]:$i:10}")
    slice=("${slice[@]/#/$LogPath/}")
    if { cat <<________EOF
        set ftp:ssl-allow no
        set xfer:use-temp-file on
        set xfer:temp-file-name *.tmp
        set log:file/xfer /log/LFTP_$FILE.log;
________EOF
        printf "mput %s\n" "${slice[@]}" 
        echo quit; } |
      lftp -p 2252 -u "$FTPUser,$FTPPass" "$Location"
    then
        rm "${slice[@]}"
    else
        echo "$0: Error for ${slice[@]}" >&2
    fi
done
```

Bash doesn't let you combine slicing and prefix substitution on an array in one go, so we copy the current slice to `slice` so that we can add `$LogPath/` in front of each entry.

Answer (score 0):

### Using an array:

```
cd "$LogPath"
files=( *.log )

if lftp -p 2252 -u "$FTPUser,$FTPPass" "$Location" <<EOF
    set ftp:ssl-allow no
    set xfer:use-temp-file on
    set xfer:temp-file-name *.tmp
    set log:file/xfer /log/LFTP_$FILE.log;
    mput ${files[@]:0:10}
    quit
EOF
then
    rm ${files[@]:0:10}
fi
```

### Explanations

```
${files[@]:0:10}
```

is a *parameter expansion* that retrieve only the first 10 elements